# How do I Send Request to EndPoint on application Startup

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am working on a Django project which has an API endpoint that receives a post request and sends a welcome email to the registered user, currently, I have to use a form to send this request to the endpoint, is there a way to manually read the email and name from my environmental variable and send a request once I run the app the first time? something like

```
EMAIL = 'try@test.com'
NAME = 'Bob'
```

I have this stored as an env variable already

and here is my current code

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
@login_required
def add_user(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        if not BlueUsers.objects.filter(user_email=email).exists():
            newuser_obj = BlueUsers.objects.create(user_name=name, user_email=email)
            conf_obj = Config.objects.first()
            if conf_obj:
                post_url = "{}/priv/create-user/".format(conf_obj.hostname)
                data = {
                    'name': newuser_obj.user_name,
                    'email': newuser_obj.user_email,
                    'redtree_user_id': newuser_obj.id
                }
                headers = {'data-auth-key': conf_obj.authentication_token}
                try:
                    response = requests.post(post_url, data=data, headers=headers)
                except:
                    response = None
```

I have been struggling with this

Comment: What would the reason for this be?  Given the fact this email will be sent on each and every deployment or orther application restart, that would be annoying for me as a user to get these notifications.

Comment: The reason is I don't want to manually fill a form every time, and it will execute only once since the code checks if the user already exist before sending a mail

Answer (score 0):

There is a file name `apps.py` that loads your app configuration and runs code on app startup.

Your purpose should be served by following piece of code

```py
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "myapp"

    def ready(self):
        # your model and other imports here

        email = os.environ.get('EMAIL')
        name = os.environ.get('NAME')

        if not BlueUsers.objects.filter(user_email=email).exists():
            newuser_obj = BlueUsers.objects.create(user_name=name, user_email=email)
            conf_obj = Config.objects.first()
            if conf_obj:
                post_url = "{}/priv/create-user/".format(conf_obj.hostname)
                data = {
                    'name': newuser_obj.user_name,
                    'email': newuser_obj.user_email,
                    'redtree_user_id': newuser_obj.id
                }
                headers = {'data-auth-key': conf_obj.authentication_token}
                try:
                    response = requests.post(post_url, data=data, headers=headers)
                except:
                    response = None
```

Any logic that you write inside the `ready` method of your AppConfig class is going to be executed once on each startup.